# How to search only FREE apps on Mac App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

It isn't an option in the App Store itself, and the [AppleSE answer from 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/monitoring-the-mac-app-store-for-free-applications) is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of websites that offer this option including one that I found with a quick Google:

https://theappstore.org

When you search you can select "Price: Free".